# My SharePoint Designer's Workflow's "Send Email" action is not sending email

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow

I ran a check for error in my SPD 2013 and it shows none. However, it does not send out the email. I read in here that someone switched to SPD 2010 workflow format and then it sent out the email. Is that the only solution?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of known issue in SPD 2013 workflow. Send mail action is not working in 2013 but it works perfect in 2010 version.
To fix this issue in SPD 2013, You can use 'Pause for Duration' action before 'Send email' action and set it for 1 min, after that it will works as per your expectation. 

[image]

Comment: This issue has been fixed in SPD 2013 as of today. Seems like it was one of my action tasks that prevented the workflow from executing the emails.